# Cannot import some builtin modules from embedded boost python

Tags: ubuntu, boost-python, python-3.9, python-embedding

I am running python scripts from within my C++ application using `boost::python`. I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'`. Some builtin modules work, but some don't. For example, `import sys` works.

I verified that I have a normal python installation and the modules are all imported correctly when I run python from command line.

I printed `sys.path`, `sys.executable`, `sys.version`, `sys.builtin_module_names` in both the embedded version and the command line version and there is only one difference - the builtin modules list is shorter when run from inside my C++ executable, with some modules are missing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps reading [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EmbeddedPython) would be helpful to you

Comment: @Gahan I read it don't see anything relevant in that link. Maybe its something going over my head?

Comment: do you know about difference between embedded system v/s the normal x86 system that we use?

Comment: No sorry, I don't.

Comment: that's where you need to start if you are working on embedded system, because it differs at assembly level on number instruction, hence once you explore it you will know answer to your question!

Comment: @Gahan In the context of Boost.Python [embedding](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html) refers to integration of the Python interpreter with a C++ executable, in order to be able to call Python code from C++. It has nothing to do with "embedded systems" you mention.

Comment: I made a correction, do you know how to call these modules from boost:: python?

Comment: @Dan Mašek that clarification is now done from OP.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I  am running into the exact same problem.

I am running on RHEL 7 and am building a shared library that is part of a complex system. Of the following 4 calls, only calendar fails (returns null):

```
PyObject* t1 = PyImport_ImportModule("calendar");
PyObject* t2 = PyImport_ImportModule("itertools");
PyObject* t3 = PyImport_ImportModule("appdirs");
PyObject* t4 = PyImport_ImportModule("cython");
```

After trying a whole bunch of different modules/packages, it appears it works for built in packages like sys and itertools, AND it works for modules in site-packages (that is simple .py files in site-packages), but not when you have a full fledged package...a directory with an **init**.py file

If you put the call to PyImport_ImportModule in a try/catch block: